# Error while installing moodle 3.9 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, installation, virtualbox, moodle

I am installing moodle on a VirtualMachine.
If I use the Webinstaller (/moodle/install.php) I get following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'object' as class name as it is reserved in
> /var/www/html/moodle/lib/setuplib.php on line 66

Using php7.4, added all Packages as required and recommended in [moodleDocs](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/PHP#PHP_Extensions_and_libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not installing Moodle 3.9 - it sounds like you are trying to install an old version such as Moodle 2.9 (or similar), as the line in question (`class object extends stdClass {};`) was deprecated in Moodle 3.1 and completely removed in Moodle 3.4.

Earlier versions of Moodle are not compatible with PHP 7.4.

Comment: I checked the moodle version (/var/www/html/version.php) and i have installed version 3.0 not 3.9 as I said. So I installed the newest version of moodle. Now I can access the webinstallation screen. So Thank you!